# Facebook non-expiring access token

Tags: facebook, token

I want to show the last facebook post on my website. I have a script for it but it needs access token to work.

I followed the steps mentioned in this post:

https://neosmart-stream.de/de/facebook/how-to-create-a-facebook-access-token/comment-page-1/#comment-617

Now I've got an access token with an expiry period of 60 days but
when I open https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts, I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

as my access token validity is 2 months, It is supposed to work.

Comment: Check the obtained token in debugger properly. This error occurs only when there's issue with the access token. Are you able to proceed with the normal access token ?

Comment: I've checked in in debugger, 
Expires: (number) (in about 2 months)
Valid: True
Origin: Web

With ne normal access token it still works

Answer (score 7):

1: Create an application in facebook with your website url

2: Run this link in your browser

3: Visit the following to generate a new SHORT-LIVED (1 hour) access token:

```
https://www.facebook.com?client_id=[APPID]&client_secret=[APPSECRET]&redirect_uri[http://APPURL]&scope=manage_pages,read_stream&response_type=token
```

4: Take that short-lived access token and send it here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

5: Then, either in FB’s Graph API Explorer or on your own, visit here:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[TOKEN]

Then paste the token and id in the code, then you will get the result.

You can debug and verify the expiration date of your token using the [FaceBook Access Token Debugger:](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken)

Comment: I got access token valid for 60days only. I think everybody wants to get one which never expires

Answer (score 1):

> when i'll open https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts...

You need to open it in the Graph API Explorer and add the access token retrieved in the earlier step **or** append it to end of the url

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXX`

Comment: if i append it to end of the url, the output is: 

{
   "data": [
      
   ]
}

edit: same output in Graph API Explorer

Comment: @user1915882 go here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts reply with what you got

Comment: {
      "category": "Application",
      "name": "Intranet-Schnittstelle",
      "access_token": "AAACEdEose0cBAPu2BhO66FLYa1kumLHU4g07d1tlVPzJZA5Xr5gXNIgSdPeZCZAUoUHhfyeVql6ecWvmxTKy6dyccI6GLjlXpwRNpyHeQeN68w21ySQAKFgbBOZA98QZD",
      "id": "189315704541822"
    }

Comment: @user1915882 maybe try redoing the auth process if that doesn't work file a bug