# How to fetch data from my facebook page without token expired?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to make an application to fetch data from my Facebook page and display it in my application.

I tried using the Facebook API Explorer, it work fine but it expires after around 1 hour.

So, I need another way to get access to all my post like text, image and videos without expire data and anyone download my app can show my post without login to Facebook or any authentication.

Comment: please can you tell me how you fetch the data from fabebook page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-expiring Page Access Token are seemingly no longer possible with Graph API v2.0. If you have a v1.0 App, you could use the way described at [Facebook non-expiring access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953265/facebook-non-expiring-access-token) to get a non-expiring Page Access Token.

Comment: So Can you help me how i Will make it?

Comment: It's all described in the answer. You'll have to do it yourself.