# Prolonging the lifespan of a page access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First of all, before this is marked as a duplicate. I have seen question similar to this one. But none of them seem up to date with the new facebook developer layout.

I have followed the instructions for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php).

Which has proved very successful. Apart from the fact that ones `page access token` changes rapidly(??!).

So I then went on to learn about prolonging the lifespan of the `page access token`. Which I found nothing of use!

I have looked at this method where you insert your app-id, app-secret and the short lived token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

but it just returns:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application. Invalid application ID.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

Does anybody have an up to date methods?

Comment: You have a type on the URL: The first `&` should be a `?`

Comment: Thank you I now have the error - as seen in updated question

Comment: Make sure you use the correct app_id of one of your apps

Comment: Do you know of any ways to keep this up to date? Or do I have to re enter it every 60 days?

Comment: With v2.0 you seemingly only can have 60 day tokens, with v1.0 there can be non-expiring ones

Comment: Can you degrade to v1.0?

Comment: Not if your app was created after April 30th 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get non-expiring Page Access Tokens, have a look at [How to fetch data from my facebook page without token expired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139900/how-to-fetch-data-from-my-facebook-page-without-token-expired/24157584#24157584)

Apparently this only work if one uses a v1.0 to get the Access Tokens, with v2.0 the lifespan is 60 days.

Comment: Is there a said way to now update it, every 60 days?

Comment: could I not just create a new one every time the page is called?

Comment: If you want to have two extra calls with each page load, then yes

Comment: how could I go about doing that?

Comment: also I don't understand how to set it up? what is `use Facebook\FacebookSession;`

Comment: is there a way to check whether the post is succesfull?

Comment: There's enough sample code on the dev homepage where you can read about that.