# Error validating access token: Session has expired

Tags: php, facebook, token

```
<?php
    require_once("facebook.php"); // set the right path

    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '';
    $config['secret'] = '';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
    $fb = new Facebook($config);

    $params = array(
      // this is the main access token (facebook profile)
      "access_token" => "EAAHHbZBnyVlsBAFx1X4LVrxouuTYZB5IDsd7PI2FQica9tqNNvzInPKP9KHPQKJPfxITGy6ZCuSjOFPChrD4f5damVXSeC2O6w7BZATUNp7s8nTZBVn8ZBdyKuVpbQeTU4mZBVrUJ92IUwP7Ubli9JJuUrtqZAwOe1ZCv751ZBNOoO80fXyATn0ztaU8OQZD",
      "message" => "",
       "name" => "",
      "caption" => "",
      "description" => ""
    );

    try {
      $ret = $fb->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $params);
      echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Personal Profile';
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

I have created a server-side PHP app that posts status automatically on my FB page but When I run the app, it shows an error message:

```
Error validating access token: Session has expired
```

Comment: Remove snippet and related app, you gave us your tokens :<

Comment: Perhaps this post may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953265/facebook-non-expiring-access-token?rq=1

Comment: [In general](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) your access token is not static, you have to learn about oauth or at least use sdk in a proper way.

Comment: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php  --- VIew Here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
require_once("facebook.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '';
$config['secret'] = '';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
  "access_token" => "EAAHHbZBnyVlsBAFx1X4LVrxouuTYZB5IDsd7PI2FQica9tqNNvzInPKP9KHPQKJPfxITGy6ZCuSjOFPChrD4f5damVXSeC2O6w7BZATUNp7s8nTZBVn8ZBdyKuVpbQeTU4mZBVrUJ92IUwP7Ubli9JJuUrtqZAwOe1ZCv751ZBNOoO80fXyATn0ztaU8OQZD", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

  "message" => "",
  "link" => "",
  "picture" => "",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "",
  "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**Try This.... http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php
Add Your AppId , Secret key ., and your facebook id in the code !!**